# Compiling application for mac with PyQt5

Tags: python, macos, pyqt5

I have finished application that was written in pyqt5 and compilled for windows(.exe file) with pyinstaller.
Can i do the same for mac? I wanna get the same application but for mac.
How can i do this? Thanks.

Comment: use returned pyinstaller in Mac OS.

Comment: @eyllanesc Can i do this in Windows?

Comment: You have to do it on Mac OS, you can not do it from windows. pyinstaller is not cross-compiler, that is indicated in the first paragraphs of https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/

Comment: @eyllanesc I've understood. Thank's